# div background image is not showing on scrolling back to div

Tags: html, css, background-image, fixed

I'm having very strange problem . I'm making one page website and have different background image for different section and background attachment is fixed. On page reload it show the background image but when I scroll down or up and go back to the section its not showing background image. if I select the page with Ctrl+a then it shows but background image but not fixed anymore. It just happening in chrome. I tried to to find the solution on google and here but could not find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide CSS + HTML or a link

Comment: can you create a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: I tried to separate the section and its working fine but not in my page. and i have the same coding for another section and its working perfect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dbms28wr/

Comment: question is vague. can you please elaborate.. with  code mostly

Comment: Why don't you use background-image: url(yourBackground.png); in CSS for the background you want?

Comment: @ManuelChoucino just using **background:** is absolutely fine. It's just a shortened version where you can add most attributes in one go as opposed to background-attachment:, background-size:, background-position:, background-image:, background-whatever:, background-etc: